# Ansible unable to reach multiple hosts

Tags: ssh, ansible

I'm new to ansible but are having basic issues reaching multiple hosts via ansible. I'm able to reach all hosts via ssh and also if I use ansible to target any specific host in my inventory. It successfully reaches one of my hosts but fails all the others.

If I run:

```
ansible all -i inventory.yml -u oytal -m ping
```

It returns:

```
192.168.1.90 | SUCCESS => {
    "ansible_facts": {
        "discovered_interpreter_python": "/usr/bin/python3"
    },
    "changed": false,
    "ping": "pong"
}


192.168.1.21 | UNREACHABLE! => {
    "changed": false,
    "msg": "Failed to connect to the host via ssh: oytal@192.168.1.21: Permission denied (publickey).",
    "unreachable": true
}


192.168.1.20 | UNREACHABLE! => {
    "changed": false,
    "msg": "Failed to connect to the host via ssh: oytal@192.168.1.20: Permission denied (publickey).",
    "unreachable": true
}


192.168.1.100 | UNREACHABLE! => {
    "changed": false,
    "msg": "Failed to connect to the host via ssh: oytal@192.168.1.100: Permission denied (publickey).",
    "unreachable": true
}
```

It's not consistent which host is unreachable, I shifted around the order of my hosts and even removed the successful one, and it will reach one of the others instead but still fail the rest.

My inventory:

```
---
all:
    hosts:
        192.168.1.90:
        192.168.1.21:
        192.168.1.20:
        192.168.1.100:
```

Comment: Try the hosts group tag, make sure that oytal is in the sudo group on each host, or at least has the proper perms for ssh - try 'ansible -i inventory.yml -l hosts -u oytal -m ping, so using the --limit parameter on the group

Comment: I'm not sure, if "grouping" the hosts will resolve the problems. I think, there is a different problem that hosts can be sometimes reached via SSH and sometimes not. That can't be a problem with Ansible but with the environment. Of course, be sure, that the user can reach ALL hosts via SSH.

Comment: I doubt, running by the same user, `ssh oytal@192.168.1.21` can connect and `ansible ... -u oytal` can't. This would suggest some kind of SSH keys misconfiguration i.e. Ansible and SSH utilities are configured to use different keys (and not all public keys are stored in authorized_keys at remote hosts).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I finally found the solution to my issue. I feel kinda dumb but it was because my id_ed25519 was encrpyted.

I entered following commands to fix the issue:

```
ssh-agent bash

ssh-add /home/$USER/.ssh/id_ed25519
```

Answer (score 1):

> Permission denied (publickey)

when running `ssh oytal@192.168.1.21` (and other hosts) means sshd at 192.168.1.21 (and other hosts) is not able to get the public key of the user running the ssh command from `/home/oytal/.ssh/authorized_keys` at 192.168.1.21 (and other hosts), by default.

There may be many reasons for this. Make sure ssh command works

shell> ssh oytal@192.168.1.21

Next, make sure Ansible uses the correct private key (see `ansible-doc -t connection ssh). Try and set it manually. For example

```sh
shell> ANSIBLE_PRIVATE_KEY_FILE=$HOME/.ssh/id_rsa ansible 192.168.1.21 -i inventory.yml -u oytal -m ping
```

Review inventory and Ansible configuration

```sh
shell> ansible-config dump
```

If this doesn't help see other [Permission denied (publickey)](https://stackexchange.com/search?q=Permission+denied+%28publickey%29) answers explaining possible reasons for the error.

Answer (score 0):

Solution:

"Log in & log out the all remote servers first. Then, ping to the remote servers with ansible."

I also couldn't ping to multiple remote servers so I did the solution above.
Then, I could ping to the all remote servers.

I don't know what's happening backside but I guess that we need to leave the fingerprints of the master server to the all remote server first before pinging to the remote servers with ansible.